# Current Store View configurable products option label translation

Tags: store-view, localisation

For some reason I don't know the attribute option/labels for store view is not working and I don't want to use csv files for translations, therefore I find out that the options are generated by Code/Core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php

I managed to translate the attribute label by changing the `$productAttribute->getLabel() to $productAttribute->getStoreLabel()` in line 170

However the attribute options labels are still showing the Global label instead of store view label.

How can make the `'label' => $value['label']` to something like above to show the current store view option label?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Question is a little bit older, but i had the same problem! And maybe there are some others :-)

**So, my solution:**

Go to `Catalog -> Manage Products` and edit your **super product**.

Goto Tab `Associated products`. 
In `Super product attributes configuration` check for each configurable attribute the `Use default`. Then, Magento will use the default translation like normal attributes (which you have to define in `Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> Edit Attribute -> Manage Labale/Options`.

Comment: Is there a way to change those automatcally somehow so I would not need to go through all configurable products manually and click them selected?

Comment: @Webninja Did you solve this issue? I'm also facing the same. Can you please guide?